# Dropdown cut off in a overflow hidden container with loadmask and fixed width

Tags: html, css

A fixed width container, with vertical scrollbar (if more items than fit in the viewport)  - this means browser sets overflow-x to auto.

Now inside it are cards with form elements. Each card has a loadmask.
Form elements can have a dropdown (date, multiselect etc) - but they are cut off if they do not fit in the sidebar.

The jsfiddle example shows the problem:
Blue area is the potential dropdown list.
Green is the loadmask.

If i remove relative position from the card class, blue menu works as intended - but loadmask is broken.

How can i get both of them to work?

http://jsfiddle.net/wLnhh0uz/

CSS:

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 280px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

.card {
  width: 240px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}

.formitem {
  height: 60px;
}

.absoluteformitem {
  position: absolute;
}

.absoluteformitem .absoluteitem {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 100;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.loadmask {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="formitem">
        formitem1
      </div>
      <div class="formitem absoluteformitem">
        <div class="absoluteitem"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="formitem">
        formitem3
      </div>
      <div class="formitem">
        formitem4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="loadmask"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="formitem">
        formitem1
      </div>
      <div class="formitem">
        formitem2
      </div>
      <div class="formitem">
        formitem3
      </div>
      <div class="formitem">
        formitem4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="loadmask"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you have attached wrong jsfiddle.Please update it.

Comment: Please update your jsfiddle link, its wrong, or you can check https://jsfiddle.net/sandymizz/rgay6htj/ if i am not wrong.

Comment: updated jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can make below changes for loadmask and then remove position for card

```
position: relative;
```

please check below link

http://jsfiddle.net/wLnhh0uz/42/

Hope this will help you!

Comment: If you look at your fiddle - the green loadmask no longer covers the card - but shows up as a new element at the bottom of  the card.

Comment: Also your blue element is now fixed and won't scroll with the card.